# get `abcde` to put different formats in different directories

Tags: ripping, abcde

I want to rip audio CDs to both mp3 and flac format using abcde.  I want the files to be in completely different directory trees, e.g. `~/Music/mp3/<artist>/<album>/<track>.mp3` and `~/Music/flac/<artist>/<album>/<track>.flac`.

Is there a way to configure the `.abcde.conf` such that I can route the multiple file formats into different locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed this by creating separate configuration files `abcde.conf.mp3`, `abcde.conf.flac` and then just selecting the one to use on the command line, e.g. `abcde -c abcde.conf.mp3`.